# 502/503 errors missed in Apache log

Tags: apache-2.2

Users of my website are getting html error 502/503.  But Apache is not logging these.  In my Apache access_log I cannot see any request for which returned html error code was 50x.

How can I count number of 50x errors my users are getting in a day ?

My configuration is as follows
I have 1 Ha-proxy and 2 severs running Apache.

Answer (score 0):

A 502 or 503 would indicate the error is coming from HAProxy, so it's not involving the Apache servers at all. You'll need to have those logged by HAProxy itself.